# Get value from column using a column name string c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists..

The first contains rows with mapping values inlcuding column name, xcord, ycord

The second contains the data I need to map..

I need to get the value in each row using the column name from the first row..

for example

```
List<SheetMappings> smaps = new List<SheetMappings>();

foreach(maplist m in mlist)
{
  SheetMappings newMap = new SheetMappings();

  foreach(vallist v in vlist)
  {
    newMap.Value = v.{m.ColumnName};

    newMap.xCord = m.xCord;

    newMap.yCord = m.yCord;
  }

  smaps.Add(newMap);
}
```

Any assitance appreciated

Cheers

Graham

EDIT:

```
List<SpreadMappings> spreadMapping = new List<SpreadMappings>(); 
foreach (var m in mappings) 
{ 
    foreach (var v in hvalues) 
    { 
        SpreadMappings map = new SpreadMappings(); 
        switch (m.ColumnName) 
        { 
            case “DocHeading”: 
                map.ColumnX = m.ColumnX; 
                map.ColumnY = m.ColumnY; 
                map.ColumnValue = v.DocHeading; 
                map.ColumnName = m.ColumnName; 
                map.ColumnId = v.Id; 
                map.ColumnSheetName = sheetName; spreadMapping.Add(map); 
            break;
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer without some more info about the data in each collection and you probably need to clarify ewhat you mean by 'I need to get the value in each row using the column name from the first row.'.... but i suspect LINQ will be the answer here

Comment: `v.{m.ColumnName}` looks suspicious to me.  I've never seen a similar construct in C# code.  Are you sure this code compiles?

Comment: @Adam That is pseudo code for what he thinks should work

Comment: the v.{m.columnName} is what I need to get, its just for 'example' purpose as I dont know the correct code (sorry)... ie the value of the row column v using the name of the column

Comment: v can have different columns depending on the table being processed...

Comment: List<SpreadMappings> spreadMapping = new List<SpreadMappings>();
foreach (var m in mappings)
 {
foreach (var v in hvalues)
{
SpreadMappings map = new SpreadMappings();
switch (m.ColumnName)
{
case “DocHeading”:
 map.ColumnX = m.ColumnX;
 map.ColumnY = m.ColumnY;
 map.ColumnValue = v.DocHeading;
 map.ColumnName = m.ColumnName;
 map.ColumnId = v.Id;
 map.ColumnSheetName = sheetName;
 spreadMapping.Add(map);
 break;

Comment: @fgt: See the link named "edit" below your question? Click that, post your code there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you'll need to use reflection to get the value of the property represented by m.ColumnName:

```
var smaps = new List<SheetMappings>(); 

foreach(maplist m in mlist) 
{
    var pi = typeof(vallist).GetProperty(m.ColumnName);

    var newMap = new SheetMappings(); 

    foreach(vallist v in vlist) 
    {
        newMap.Value = pi.GetValue(v, null); 
        newMap.xCord = m.xCord; 
        newMap.yCord = m.yCord; 
    } 
    smaps.Add(newMap); 
}
```

So that's using reflection to get a reference to the PropertyInfo for the property represented by `m.ColumnName`, then calling `PropertyInfo.GetValue` to get the value of that property from v.

Comment: Matt, many thanks that works fine! cuts down the code by miles..my next quest is to have the entities created during run time so the users can add tables and columns when required.. I'm sure I will be back on that one...

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the "newMap.Value = v.{m.ColumnName}" part would be something like:

```
newMap.Value = v.FirstOrDefault( vitem => vitem.ColumnName == m.ColumnName );
```

This would give you the first item within "v" that has a "ColumnName" property that matches the "ColumnName" property of "m". This assumes that the contents of "vallist" are objects that have a "ColumnName" property.

Comment: but the m.columnname will always be a valid column in the vallist objects

Comment: If the objects in vallist don't have anything to associate them with a column how can m.columnname be used to locate an object in vallist?

Comment: because I use the switch statement as per above example code posted and hardcode the assignment of v.docheading... but I want to find these dynamically asthese columns can be changed or added by the users